# How can you end your game with text on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

For my multiple choice program, when the user runs out of lives, the text "Game Over" pops up on screen. However, when I added this, the multiple choice options still remain on screen with the question, and they can still carry on with the game. The "Game Over" text then suddenly disappears if they carry on.

Below is my a snippet of the relevant part of my code:

```
    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        self.gamestate.answer(n)
                        if self.gamestate.questions:
                            return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
                        else:
                            quit()
                    n += 1



class QuitScene:
    def __init__(self):
        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
        self.gamestate = gamestate

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        game_over_surf = font100.render("Game Over", True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(game_over_surf, game_over_surf.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                quit()
            if self.gamestate.questions and self.gamestate.lives > 0:
                            return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
            elif self.gamestate.lives == 0:
                        return ('QUIT',)
            n += 1


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1275, 775))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    scenes = {
        'TITLE': SimpleScene('SETTING', 'You have chosen category 1: Introduction to Programming ', '', '', '', 'press [SPACE] to start'),
        'SETTING': SettingScene(),
        'GAME': GameScene(),
        'QUIT': QuitScene(),
    }
    scene = scenes['TITLE']
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        game = scene.update(events, dt)
        if game:
            next_scene, state = game
            if next_scene:
                scene = scenes[next_scene]
                scene.start(state)


        scene.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a way in which the game will stop completely when the lives run out but the "Game Over" text will stay on the screen? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, I believe this code will help you:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import pygame.freetype
import random

X = 1275
Y = 775
green = (50, 205, 50)
blue = (0, 0, 205)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((X,Y))
font100 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

Heart = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Davina/Documents/Python/Testing/Hearts.png")
Heart1 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Davina/Documents/Python/Testing/Hearts.png")
Heart2 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Davina/Documents/Python/Testing/Hearts.png")



class SimpleScene:
    FONT = None

    def __init__(self, next_scene, *text):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))

        y = 200
        if text:
            if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
                SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)
            for line in text:
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (220, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (220, y - 1), line, pygame.Color('black'))
                y += 50

        self.next_scene = next_scene
        self.additional_text = None

    def start(self, text):
        self.additional_text = text

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        if self.additional_text:
            y = 180
            for line in self.additional_text:
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (120, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
                SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (119, y - 1), line, pygame.Color('white'))
                y += 50

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    return (self.next_scene, None)


class GameState:
    def __init__(self, difficulty):
        self.difficulty = difficulty

        self.lives = 3

        # CHANGE
        self.questions = [
            ("Q1: Choose the correct symbol. 4 __ 6 = 10 ?"),
            ("Q2: Variables store data. Choose the appropriate variable. ______ = 1"),
            ("Q3: What should be the output?    Number = 1    Total = Number * 3    print(Total)")
                         ]
        self.answers = [4, 1, 2]
        self.current_question = None

        # CHANGE
        self.question_index = 0


    def pop_question(self):
        q = self.questions[0]
        self.current_question = q
        return q


    def answer(self, answer):
        if answer != self.answers[self.question_index]:
            self.lives -= 1
        else:
            self.question_index += 1
            self.questions.pop(0)

class SettingScene:

    def __init__(self):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))

        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (120, 50), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('black'))
        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (119, 49), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('black'))

        self.rects = []

        # CHANGE
        for n in range(4):
            rect = pygame.Rect(50, (n * 70) + 100, 500, 50)
            self.rects.append(rect)

    def start(self, *args):
        pass

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        n = 1
        for rect in self.rects:
            if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect, 5)

            # CHANGE
            SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 30, rect.y + 15), str(n), pygame.Color('black'))
            SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 29, rect.y + 14), str(n), pygame.Color('black'))

            n += 1

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        return ('GAME', GameState(n))
                    n += 1

class GameScene:
    def __init__(self):
        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

        self.rects = []

        for n in range(4):
            rect = pygame.Rect(420, (n * 70) + 300, 500, 50)
            self.rects.append(rect)

        # CHANGE
        self.choices = [['x', '-', '*', '+'], ["number", "fruit", "weather", "letter"], ["4", "3", "-2", "13"]]

    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
        self.gamestate = gamestate
        question = gamestate.pop_question()
        SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (20, 150), question, (blue))

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))

        if self.gamestate.lives >= 1:
            screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))
        if self.gamestate.lives >= 2:
            screen.blit(Heart1, (X // 2, 10))
        if self.gamestate.lives >= 3:
            screen.blit(Heart2, (775, 10))
        if self.gamestate.lives == 0:
            game_over_surf = font100.render("Game Over", True, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(game_over_surf, game_over_surf.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))



        n = 0
        for rect in self.rects:
            if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'),
                             rect, 5)

            # CHANGE
            for i in range(len(self.choices)):
                if self.gamestate.question_index == i:
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 30, rect.y + 20), str(self.choices[i][n]),
                                               (green))
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 29, rect.y + 19), str(self.choices[i][n]),
                                               (green))
            n += 1

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        self.gamestate.answer(n)
                        if self.gamestate.questions and self.gamestate.lives > 0:
                            return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
                    elif self.gamestate.lives == 0:
                        return ('QUIT', self.gamestate)
                    else:
                        quit() # Here the program ends after the third question is answered correctly and you have more than 0 lives
                    n += 1

class QuitScene:
    def __init__(self):
        if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
            SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

    def start(self, gamestate):
        self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
        self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
        self.gamestate = gamestate

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        game_over_surf = font100.render("Game Over", True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(game_over_surf, game_over_surf.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))

    def update(self, events, dt):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                quit() # You have to add another behaviour here if you want to avoid closing the app after mouse button down



def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1275, 775))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    scenes = {
        'TITLE': SimpleScene('SETTING', 'You have chosen category 1: Introduction to Programming ', '', '', '', 'press [SPACE] to start'),
        'SETTING': SettingScene(),
        'GAME': GameScene(),
        'QUIT': QuitScene(),
    }
    scene = scenes['TITLE']
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        game = scene.update(events, dt)
        if game:
            next_scene, state = game
            if next_scene:
                scene = scenes[next_scene]
                scene.start(state)



        scene.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've modified the `GameScene` class. In the `update` method there was a call to `quit()`. That call closes the app completely. So I've added a new scene that is the `QuitScene` and it shows the Game Over text in the screen and after you click, the app is closed. If you don't want to close it, I've added a comment indicating where you have to modify the code to change that behavior.

Comment: What should happen after all the questions are correct? Because you could add a new variable to `gamestate` with the text you want to show, just before the `return ('QUIT', self.gamestate)`. And then you could use that variable here `game_over_surf = font100.render("Game Over", True, (0, 0, 0))` instead the "Game Over" string. Would be something like `game_over_surf = font100.render(self.gamestate.finaltext, True, (0, 0, 0))`

Comment: You can do something like:
`if self.gamestate.questions and self.gamestate.lives > 0:
    return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
elif self.gamestate.lives == 0:
    return ('QUIT', self.gamestate)`

Sorry for the formatting.

The only problem with that code, is that you still need to handle what happens when the user wins.

Comment: I will edit my answer code with that code. Done.

Comment: I ran your edited version of the code but it's still not working. Check my updated version of my question to see the image. Ideally, I'm looking for nothing on the screen if the lives is more than zero.

Comment: Is it possible for the program to end after the third question? Given that they have more than zero lives? I can use this if the user wins.

Comment: Hey, check my updated code, I changed a bit of your code so that the game will not stop after the first question. The only problem is that the game continues playing with the "Game Over" text in the background. The pictures are in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227724/discussion-between-lucas-belfanti-and-davina).